# How can $2\cos(x-\frac{\pi}2) = -2\sin(x-\frac{\pi}2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can $2\cos(x-\dfrac{\pi}2) = -2\sin(x-\dfrac{\pi}2)$

I know that  $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$ and that $\cos(\dfrac{\pi}2-x) = \sin(x)$

From these two formulas I can get

$1.$ $2\cos(x-\dfrac{\pi}2) = 2\cos(\dfrac{\pi}2-x)$

$2.$ $2\cos(\dfrac{\pi}2-x) = 2 \sin(x)$

$3.$ $ 2\sin(x) = -2\sin(-x)$

$4.$ How can I get $-2\sin(-x) = -2\sin(x-\dfrac{\pi}2)$

It was part of calculation of limit:

$lim_{x->(\dfrac{\pi}{2})} \dfrac{1-e^{2cosx}}{2cosx} \dfrac{2cos(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2})}{sin(4(x-\dfrac{\pi}{x}))}$

and from there in the next step we assumed the identity I mentioned above

Comment: This equality is not true in general: $$-2\sin(x-\pi/2)=2\sin(\pi/2-x)=2\cos x\ne LHS=2\sin x$$It is only true for $x=n\pi+\pi/4,n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This is not an identity working for all $x$, $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ trivially does not work. But rather an equation you need to solve

Comment: Perhaps you had to solve **an equation**? This is obviously not an identity: just input $\;x=0\;$ to get a contradiction...

Comment: It was part of calculation of limit: $lim_{x->(\dfrac{\pi}{2})} \dfrac{1-e^{2cosx}}{2cosx} \dfrac{2cos(x-\dfrac{\pi}{2})}{sin(4(x-\dfrac{\pi}{x}))}$

and from there in the next step we assumed the identity I mentioned in my original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2\cos\left(x-\dfrac\pi2\right)=-2\sin\left(x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$$

$$\implies\tan\left(x-\dfrac\pi2\right)=-1=\tan\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

$$\implies x-\dfrac\pi2=n\pi-\dfrac\pi4$$ where $n$ is any integer

Clearly, the given relationship is not an identity